# Frozen Synapse started crashing with a "Unable to initialize OpenGL" error after upgrade

Tags: 11.10, intel, opengl, games

I just played Frozen Synapse 2 days ago using Ubuntu 11.04. Now with a clean upgrade of 11.10, I cannot play the game anymore. When I run the game in terminal I get this error:

```
Alert: Error Unable to initialize OpenGL.  (Error: Failed loading libGL.so.1)
Exiting
```

What could be the problem? I'm using Intel graphics adapter by the way. The one that Intel Corei3 comes in stock in Laptops.

Comment: Sounds like the same kind of trouble Skype is having. Try with the 32bit version...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an issue with the way the libraries are handled.

see the thread: http://frozenbyte.com/board/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=3706

The developers are reporting:

"It seems that libglade has no multiarch support, it's mainly a shared library packaging issue, but we are too late in debian and ubuntu developpement cycle to ask for a fix. Is there any alternative to request request repackaging this library to get this installer (and game) to run in Oneiric ?"

They are apparently working on a solution. For now my Frozenbyte Humble Bundle programs simply do not run on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I hope they are working on a solution right now. I cannot play FrozenSynapse anymore. I don't want to revert to 11.04 either. By the way, will FrozenSynapse work out-of-the-box in Fedora 15?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem running "Trine 64bit" on my recent ubuntu 11.10 installation. I fix it installing some additional packages.

libgladeui-2-0
libgladeui-common
libglade2-0

After installing these packages incomes a new problem due to the lack o S3TC extensions on the intel opensource drivers. I finally fix this problem installing some packages from the [xorg-edges ppa](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/357631)

Now Trine is running fine. Maybe the same solution can work for Synapse.

Comment: I fixed Trine in a similar manner, but Frozen Synapse and others are not fixed. My guess is a few more missing libraries.

Comment: Yep. I still get the same error. I'll try Trine later and get you some update about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on amd64 version of oneiric and here's what I had to do.

1. Install `ia32-libs`
2. Run FS like this: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa ./FrozenSynapse`