# Unable to run apps requiring OpenGL support

Tags: graphics, radeon, opengl

Recently upgraded my onboard Nvidea graphics chip with an ATI Radeon Sapphire X800XL  PCIe graphics card. Ever since I am unable to run Stellarium. I get the error "This system does not support OpenGL". The only thing that has changed since I last run Stellarium (other than the weekly updates) is the new card. I have tried other fixes like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66364/frozen-synapse-started-crashing-with-a-unable-to-initialize-opengl-error-after) to no avail. I have also tried to re-install the ATI plugin and Catalyst drivers in Software Center with no change. I remember once finding the list of Nvidea drivers available and being able to switch between them, where is that box again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on [Ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1724456)

It looks like my new ATI drivers were conflicting with the old Nvidea ones that required the boot first, like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh #don't worry if this command fails
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

After completing the Nvidea purge and ATI re-install all works well :)