# OpenGL - libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported

Tags: wine, qt, opengl, wayland, 21.10

Good morning,
whenever I try to run any OpenGL powered Application like **Free Download Manager** or **WINE powered Games** like **GTA San Andreas** i find that libGL is broken...

Output of **/opt/freedownloadmanager/fdm**

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Gtk-Message: 21:11:36.584: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Model size of -1 is less than 0
Model size of -1 is less than 0
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
```

Output of **wine "/sdc/Games/GTA San Andreas/gta_sa.exe"**

```
0148:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0140:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0148:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0140:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0158:fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND/RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT 1000
0158:fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND/RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/DATA_SEND_TIMEOUT 1000
0158:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0158:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0351F87C 1 C) semi-stub
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
libGL error: GLX drawable type is not supported
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request:  167
  Current serial number in output stream:  167
```

Please note that i tried the following methods which didn't work:

- http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-opengl-ubuntu-linux/ (it advised me to install **sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev mesa-utils**)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/113762/1067284 (it advised me to run

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

)

and when i tried to follow this warning:

> Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.

```
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
```

**/opt/freedownloadmanager/fdm** results in:

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Failed to load client buffer integration: wayland-egl

Model size of -1 is less than 0
Model size of -1 is less than 0
qt.qpa.wayland: No shell integration named "xdg-shell" found
qt.qpa.wayland: No shell integration named "xdg-shell-v6" found
qt.qpa.wayland: No shell integration named "wl-shell" found
qt.qpa.wayland: No shell integration named "ivi-shell" found
qt.qpa.wayland: Loading shell integration failed.
qt.qpa.wayland: Attempted to load the following shells ("xdg-shell", "xdg-shell-v6", "wl-shell", "ivi-shell")
QObject::connect: No such signal QPlatformNativeInterface::systemTrayWindowChanged(QScreen*)
```

Output of **sudo find / -name libwayland-egl.so* -print**

```
/snap/okular/109/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/okular/109/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/vlc/2344/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/vlc/2344/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/274/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/274/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/274/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/274/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/273/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/273/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/273/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/273/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/telegram-desktop/3343/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/telegram-desktop/3343/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/telegram-desktop/3455/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/telegram-desktop/3455/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/obs-studio/1276/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/obs-studio/1276/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/ffmpeg/1286/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/ffmpeg/1286/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/skype/197/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/skype/197/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/whatsapp-for-linux/28/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/whatsapp-for-linux/28/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87/usr/lib/libwayland-egl.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87/usr/lib/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87/usr/lib/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/rpi-imager/184/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/rpi-imager/184/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/postman/149/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/postman/149/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
```

Output of **sudo ldconfig -p | grep wayland-egl**

```
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone,
there was a serious problem with my Drivers... which got fixed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

thanks to: https://askubuntu.com/a/714710/1067284